# Interface for manipulating element order of a list

Tags: ruby, collections

I want a list of items (I really want a stack for FILO, but I guess it is irrelevant). Is there some implementation for manipulating the item order? Things like:

- Move x to 2 positions ahead
- Move y to 3 positions behind
- Move z to the top of position

I want to see that if something similar already exists, what other functionality it offers. I also want to use it/know how such interface works. I am doing this in Ruby, but I guess examples in other languages will be sufficient as well.

Comment: Have you read the [Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html) documentation? This is all done with basic operations. What are your performance requirements? How large are the lists you're manipulating? What kind of values are `x`, `y` and `z` anticipated to be?

Comment: I have read it, and since it is not designed for this, I am looking for stuff outside the standard library. The list will be around 1000 elements. x,y and z are elements inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Ruby hasn't built-in method to move elements inside an array, but you could add them directly into Array class, like that:

```
class Array
  def move(index, distance)
    temp = self[index+distance]
    self[index+distance] = self[index]
    self[index] = temp
    self
  end
end

a = [1,2,3]
a.move(0,1)
```

Comment: `insert(delete_at(index), index+distance)`

Comment: @steenslag, if I remember correctly, Ruby actually stores Array items in C-like arrays. So deleting an item and inserting it again is inefficient due to need of two shifts of each item of (in worst case) whole array.